# How to troubleshoot the connection error occurring while connecting data of AWS - RDS PostgreSQL with Salesforce in Einstein Analytics?

Tags: einstein-analytics

From Salesforce Einstein Analytics we are trying to connect the data through AWS-RDS PostgreSQL .
So, AWS-RDS, is in the client intranet network as well as we have integration in between this two interfaces, i.e. Salesforce and AWS-RDS PostgreSQL .
Scenario  1 : The problem we are facing while connecting the data from salesforce Analytics einstein with AWS-RDS PostgreSQL, we are getting an erro message as below :
"The connection attempt failed.. Error in Job ID connector.cs29-app2-5-ph2.4Q7z5qlJ5ihvyp0fHnkVc" .
So, do we need to do any additional step here to resolve the above error which connecting the data in Einstein Analytics.

Scenario 2 : There was another instance of AWS-RDS PostgreSQL, which was not in the client network and so it is public , where we are successfull in building the connection .

Kindly, request to expalin if there is any of the steps we are missing to connect the data through Salesforce ANalytics.

Thanks,
Kapil